# Not able to see the graphics stuff inside paint() method

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I'm doing all `Graphics` stuffs such as `g.drawLine()` etc. inside class `MyCanvas.java`

```
public class MyCanvas extends JComponent{ 
   public void paint(Graphics g){...}
}
```

And my `Main.java` class is

```
class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args){
   JFrame window = new JFrame();

   window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   window.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 350);
   window.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

   MyCanvas mc = new MyCanvas();
   JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(mc);
   jsp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

   window.getContentPane().add(jsp);
   window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   window.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

However, JFrame is only showing white plain background, It isn't showing any `Graphics` stuff from `paint(Graphics g)`.

Note that, If I remove `JScrollPane` from above `Main.java`, then it shows everything perfectly.

```
class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args){
   JFrame window = new JFrame();

   window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   window.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 350);

   window.getContentPane().add(new MyCanvas());
   window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
   window.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Where my logic is going wrong? Is there any problem while adding `JScrollPane` ? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't think code is too big. And I'm aware of MCVE, otherwise I could have written unnecessary code inside `paint()` method too.

Comment: `window.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 350);`  The 1000x350 should probably be the preferred size of the container `MyCanvas`.  Then `pack()` the frame to make it as large as it needs to be in order to show the canvas, scroll pane and frame decorations.

Comment: *"I don't think code is too big"*  I didn't say it was.  But it is also not an MCVE.  An MCVE should be copy (once) paste/compile/run/see.  For that to be so with the above sources would require 1) Class or package imports. 2) One source file.  One source file can contain more than one class, but can have only **one `public`** class.  *"I'm aware of MCVE"*  I wrote (the first draft of) the MCVE.  It was based on the SSCCE (which I also wrote).  So there is no need to tell me what it means.  Please revisit the document and read it carefully, because you are obviously not understanding it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Okay, Sorry, I'll take care next time :)

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent{ 
   public void paint(Graphics g){...}
}
```

Should be:

```
class MyCanvas extends JComponent{ 
   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g){...}
}
```

By using `paintComponent` we respect the painting chain.  Also be sure to add `super.paintComponent(g);` as the first statement in the overridden method, to assure that the BG color and borders etc. are painted.

Comment: I tried this one. But still the same. Only white plain background.

Comment: Post an MCVE for further assistance.

Comment: Theres no change in main class. Its the same as I posted. `MyCanvas.java` simply contains method like `g.drawLine()`, `g.fillRect()` etc.

Comment: If I remove `JScrollPane` from  `Main.java` then it shows everything perfectly. Please see the modified post.